# 2sxc - Content/Apps is not being imported

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I was trying to migrate specific 2sxc pages to other environments. I've tried the export and import pages feature in DNN but the content/apps has not been imported.

**DNN version:** 08.04.02
**2sxc version:** 12.18.0

Error shows:
System Exception Data: content/apps has not been imported yet

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior. By exporting/importing a site, the 2sxc Data is not included, as the internal data model can't reliably survive the Dnn data model format.

So after doing this, you should export any Apps (incl. the Content App) and select the checkbox to preserve content-blocks. Then import them again. It's described in detail https://2sxc.org/en/learn/copy-duplicate-an-entire-site